# How to integrate the JIRA and GitLab?

Tags: integration, jira, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Can anyone know how to integrate the JIRA and Gitlab?

This [Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28215) is my doubt.

**Update:**
If I need to close the JIRA task by using the triggering word means I use the **closes TP-123** triggering word in the Gitlab merge request description box. Here TP-123 is the JIRA task ID.

This is the [procedure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html#jira-issue-closing-example) to close the JIRA task by Gitlab merge request. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way are you trying to integrate Jira and Gitlab ? Please give some example use cases

Comment: @CCH I updated my question

Comment: I believe the GitLab --> JIRA integration was broken at some point, ref: the issue you linked, and my own experience!

Comment: @PeterReid Have you cleared this kind of issue? The Gitlab issue was created by me. But no one reply in Gitlab. :(

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm not admin on the gitlab instance in question, but the integration stopped working suddenly a few weeks ago

Comment: @PeterReid may I know the Gitlab edition and version ? and JIRA version?

Comment: @Arunald GitLab CE:  8.14.5, JIRA Software v7.2.6. The GitLab instance is hosted by my Uni, JIRA by myself. I'll chime in on the GitLab.com issue(s).

Comment: @PeterReid  I too using GitLab 8.14.3 but I using JIRA cloud version